# How do I say "I know what I am" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

The lack of the inflection of the verb to be in the present tense makes me confused sometimes. How would one say "I know what I am" in Russian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Я знаю, чтО/кто я есть**

The conjugation in the Present tense is dead simple - **есть** is the only form. It can be replaced with **являться** which does conjugate according to grammatical person like any standard verb.

So it can be translated also as

> **Я знаю, кем я являюсь**

A synonymous expression without the verb **to be** is

> **Я знаю, кто я такой**

Comment: It can also be dropped entirely: "Я знаю, кто я".